Water valve type under sink
I’ve moved into another house and am unfamiliar with its type of pipe. My previous house had copper pipes.
What type of pipe and valve is this?
The valve doesn’t work anymore (closing it doesn’t fully stop water flow). How do I take the valve off and replace it. Should I remove the valve by turning 2 or 3 in the picture?
I’m not sure if with this type of plastic pipe whether the valve is glued on and therefore can’t be easily removed. So, I wanted to ask before turning the valve and risk breaking it.
Thank you!


Appears to be CVPC - there isn't enough length for the full description to show up in the printing (which can be seen, in part, on the longer vertical section.) The color is typical of CPVC.
The plastic-to-plastic joints will be solvent-welded, so attempting to unscrew at 3  will just shatter the weakest part.
If you shut off the water at an earlier point, unscrewing at 2 (and 1) might allow you to remove the valve mechanism to install a new sealing washer and restore function to this valve without replacing it. That will typically be the least-cost option.
To replace it, you'll need to cut pipe and use couplings, more pipe, and solvent-welding to rebuild it the same, or a comparatively expensive slip-fit valve to replace it without solvent-welding, a bit shorter, if there's enough length on the hose leading to valve to connect to a valve a bit lower than this one. As you probably don't have CPVC primer, cement, or pipe sitting around, the more expensive valve may cost you less for now, because of all the stuff you won't have to buy just to install a less expensive valve.
